# Sane way of enumerating python versions from bash

Tags: shell-script

Due to bureaucracy, I am in a situation where I can get someone to run a bash script on a Linux server and give me outputs, but I cannot log in there, or run the script myself.

I am fairly certain that the server in question is running Debian or Ubuntu.

I want to find out which `python` and which `g++` versions are installed (long story).

So far my best idea is to get `$PATH` variable, split it by `:`, and then search all the paths for everything matching `python`, `g++` respectively.

Is there a saner way?

Comment: Is there a possibility that there are compilers/interpreters _not_ installed by the package manager? If that's not the case simply use `dpkg`

Comment: @schaiba There is, especially since I am looking for sufficiently modern version in case of `g++`. (It has to support C++14)

Comment: Won't work on all systems, but [a few more solutions from askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/505449/234837)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following should work for g++, provided that you have no local g++ installations.

```
dpkg -l 'g++*'
```

On my system, this gives:

```
dpkg -l 'g++*'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                             Version               Architecture          Description
+++-================================-=====================-=====================-======================================================================
ii  g++                              4:4.9.2-2             amd64                 GNU C++ compiler
ii  g++-4.6                          4.6.3-14              amd64                 GNU C++ compiler
un  g++-4.6-multilib                 <none>                <none>                (no description available)
ii  g++-4.9                          4.9.2-10              amd64                 GNU C++ compiler
ii  g++-4.9-multilib                 4.9.2-10              amd64                 GNU C++ compiler (multilib files)
ii  g++-multilib                     4:4.9.2-2             amd64                 GNU C++ compiler (multilib files)
```

For Python, a similar approach will pick up too many false positives, because on Debian and its derivatives, all Python libraries start with `python-`. So, one would need a more refined glob pattern.

Something like

```
dpkg -l 'python?.?'
```

should work.

```
dpkg -l 'python?.?'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                             Version               Architecture          Description
+++-================================-=====================-=====================-======================================================================
ii  python2.6                        2.6.8-1.1             amd64                 Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.6)
ii  python2.7                        2.7.9-2               amd64                 Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.7)
un  python3.1                        <none>                <none>                (no description available)
ii  python3.4                        3.4.2-1               amd64                 Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 3.4)
```

Comment: This will miss if there's `2.xx` or `3.xx`

Comment: @cuonglm True. One should come up with a more flexible version. Though has there ever been a Python `2.xx` or `3.xx` in Debian?

Comment: Of course, there're anything like that yet.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the versions that are in $PATH, you can run:
`python -V ; g++ --version`

Comment: The second version here really doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: Indeed... Edited

Comment: I am a little bit surprised, how could everybody miss this...

Comment: @peterh This will only print the first versions in your path

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
$ type -ma '(python|g++)*'
g++ is /usr/bin/g++
g++-4.4 is /usr/bin/g++-4.4
g++-4.6 is /usr/bin/g++-4.6
g++-5 is /usr/bin/g++-5
python is /usr/bin/python
python-config is /usr/bin/python-config
python-coverage is /usr/bin/python-coverage
python2 is /usr/bin/python2
python2-config is /usr/bin/python2-config
python2-coverage is /usr/bin/python2-coverage
python2-gflags2man is /usr/bin/python2-gflags2man
python2.7 is /usr/bin/python2.7
python2.7-config is /usr/bin/python2.7-config
python2.7-coverage is /usr/bin/python2.7-coverage
python3 is /usr/bin/python3
python3.2 is /usr/bin/python3.2
python3.2mu is /usr/bin/python3.2mu
python3.4 is /usr/bin/python3.4
python3.4m is /usr/bin/python3.4m
python3.5 is /usr/bin/python3.5
python3.5m is /usr/bin/python3.5m
python3m is /usr/bin/python3m
pythontex is /usr/bin/pythontex
pythontex3 is /usr/bin/pythontex3
```

Like `type cmd` but reports `a`ll the commands (and aliases and functions and builtins which would be relevant if the shell of the user happens to be `zsh`) that `m`atch the pattern.

Comment: is this like (bash) `locate g++ python | xargs | readlink -` (or thereabouts)?

Comment: This looks impressively efficient, but it's picking up stuff that's not installed. Could you explain what this command does, please?

Answer (score 3):

Just Using the OS package manager to query:

```
$ dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/ && $2 ~ /^python[0-9](\.[0-9]+)+$/ {print $2}'
python2.6
python2.7
python3.2
python3.4
```

Comment: The poster also asked about g++. If one is going to query `dpkg`, it certainly supports regular expressions, so that would be the way to go, imo.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: It's not regular expression but glob pattern.

Comment: This is nice, but what about binaries that weren't installed by package manager?

Comment: @Xarn: You need to do it by hand, this approach can not handle that situation.

Comment: @cuonglm True, glob pattern, not regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don't know everything about the system that your script will run on and you won't have an easy time fixing it, you should keep it low-tech and low-assumption.

Write a portable sh script that enumerates `PATH`. That takes care of non-package installations as well as package installation, as long as the non-package installations are in an advertised place. (If you can't trust the administrators to have made the installations you want discoverable, you're better off installing your own.)

```
#!/bin/sh
set -f; IFS=:
set -- $PATH
set +f; unset IFS
for dir; do
  if [ -x "$dir/python" ]; then printf %s "$dir/python is "; "$dir/python -V; fi
  ls -l "$dir/python"* 2>/dev/null
  if [ -x "$dir/python" ]; then printf %s "$dir/g++ is "; "$dir/g++ --version | head -n 1; fi
  ls -l "$dir/g++"* 2>/dev/null
done
```

The output of this script is just a sample, you may want to make it easier to parse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `which -a` to search the path.

```
function get_versions {
    for p in $(which -a $1); do
        $p --version
    done
}

get_versions python
get_versions g++
```